How can I call an API that calls backend APIs in Azure Data Factory without it carrying over the authentication for both?
I'm running into issues in Azure Data Factory (ADF) with an API I am working with.
I am unfortunately not at liberty to share the API URL or much data on the call I am making, but I can say that I have been testing this API call in Postman and through other tools, so I know I am using the right authentication method, URL, endpoint, etc.
When I try to call the API in ADF, I get the following error.

Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query
parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization
header should be specified

Based on what research I've done so far, it appears that the API I am calling is referencing Amazon Web Services (AWS) through a second API on the backend to fetch data. When I call the API in Postman and through other tools, it drops the initial authentication I use for the first API when it calls the second API for AWS. However, when I use ADF, it is keeping the authentication on, so when it calls the AWS API it is still using my authentication for the first API.
I haven't seen a working solution for this problem, so I was wondering if anyone has run into this problem and knows a workaround?
Any and all help is appreciated.
EDIT: I found a similar question at How can I prevent Azure Data Factory (Web Activity) from handling Redirects?, but this question remains unanswered as I add this edit, since the only provided solution is just to not use ADF.

You can't.
I reposted this question in the Microsoft Learn forum and have been informed by a Microsoft employee that there is no working method to do what I'm asking about in Azure Data Factory currently. Their statement is below. I am marking this question as completed because the answer is "you can't" and that is useful information for anyone else trying to do this. I am going to try and program this in an Azure Function, though it isn't my strong suit I'm not exactly left with options.
'After further checking with my internal team, it has been confirmed that ADF doesn't clean up the authentication header on redirect requests, causing the issue. This behavior is intentional and by design.
We have created a product backlog item for addressing this issue in a future release.
Please feel free to reach out if you have any further questions or concerns.'
Feel free to see here the forum post below for the full communication.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1669285/how-do-i-call-an-api-that-redirects-on-the-backend

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
